# Show the full path and name of all files that contain keywords in their name

Tags: linux, grep, find

I am new to the Ubuntu system.

If I want to display the full path and name of all files that contain keywords in their name. What can I do?

I've tried:

```
grep -lR "keyword" .
grep "keyword" $HOME
find /home -name "keyword"
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you get all file names that contain `keyword`:

```
find /home -type f -name "*keyword*"
```

---

See: `man find`

Comment: Thanks! I found `sudo find / -name '*keyword*' ` works for me